Why does printing cause the heap break to increase by this much?
I wrote the following program,
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "rand.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

  void *x = sbrk(0);
  printf("The initial top of the heap is %p.\n", x);
  void *y = sbrk(0);
  printf("The current top of the heap is %p.\n", y);
  printf("The difference is %d (%x)\n", (int) (y-x), (int) (y-x));
  return 0;
}

I get why the heap break is different because it has to allocate heap space for the calls to print.
What I don't get is why, on my x86_64 Linux computer, the difference is specifically 25600 bytes.
Like, the string itself probably only needs a small number of bytes (each byte a char, add a little header data to the string in the heap), nowhere near needing even 1000 bytes right?
I had a bit of a guess that it might have something to do with paging -- which I don't really understand right yet.  But from a brief search, it seems like paging only allocates about 4000 bytes at a time anyway, so that's probably not it either, right?
Maybe the various includes have something to do with it?  I honestly don't know how that affects heap memory at all.

Anyway, the direct question is: Why does this program cause the heap memory to move by 25600 bytes?

It might be that the stdout buffers and other structures and data are not allocated until the first call to printf (or any other function using stdout). There's really no memory being allocated for the format string or the generated string itself, it uses the private buffers directly.

Note that arithmetic with void * pointers is not defined by the C standard.  It's a confusing GCC extension - how big is a nothing object that doesn't have a type and doesn't exist?

@AndrewHenle I may be misunderstanding, but I thought the point of a void * was to simply look into the address itself unmitigated by the interpretation of the type system.  I mean, you may burn your retinas by doing so, but it's for science so ...

And I guess the upshot being, you'd think you'd just define plus and minus with unsigned integer arithmetic.

Like Some programmer dude said. Do another printf followed by another sbrk(0). I suspect it won't change much, if at all.

@Addem Nope.  Final conclusion: arithmetic on a void* is illegal in both C and C++.


Why does printing cause the heap break to increase by this much?

Because "printing" allocates memory, so moves the heap break. Running your program under debugger, you might observe:
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI___sbrk (increment=increment@entry=135168) at sbrk.c:37
#1  0x00007ffff7e45b36 in __glibc_morecore (increment=increment@entry=135168) at /usr/src/debug/glibc/glibc/malloc/morecore.c:29
#2  0x00007ffff7e46bfd in sysmalloc (nb=nb@entry=656, av=av@entry=0x7ffff7f87ac0 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:2709
#3  0x00007ffff7e47c5a in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7f87ac0 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=640) at malloc.c:4481
#4  0x00007ffff7e47f37 in tcache_init () at malloc.c:3252
#5  0x00007ffff7e48776 in tcache_init () at malloc.c:3248
#6  __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=bytes@entry=1024) at malloc.c:3313
#7  0x00007ffff7e21f14 in __GI__IO_file_doallocate (fp=0x7ffff7f885c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at filedoalloc.c:101
#8  0x00007ffff7e31214 in __GI__IO_doallocbuf (fp=0x7ffff7f885c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at /usr/src/debug/glibc/glibc/libio/libioP.h:1030
#9  __GI__IO_doallocbuf (fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7f885c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at genops.c:342
#10 0x00007ffff7e2f2e8 in _IO_new_file_overflow (f=0x7ffff7f885c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, ch=-1) at fileops.c:745
#11 0x00007ffff7e2fde8 in _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x7ffff7f885c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=<optimized out>, n=47)
    at /usr/src/debug/glibc/glibc/libio/libioP.h:1030
#12 _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x7ffff7f885c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=<optimized out>, n=47) at fileops.c:1197
#13 0x00007ffff7dfd549 in __printf_buffer_flush_to_file (buf=buf@entry=0x7fffffffd9b0) at ../libio/libioP.h:1030
#14 0x00007ffff7dfd60c in __printf_buffer_to_file_done (buf=buf@entry=0x7fffffffd9b0) at printf_buffer_to_file.c:120
#15 0x00007ffff7e08e0c in __vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7f885c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, 
    format=0x555555556008 "The initial top of the heap is %p.\n", ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffdab0, mode_flags=mode_flags@entry=0)
    at vfprintf-internal.c:1545
#16 0x00007ffff7dfccf3 in __printf (format=<optimized out>) at printf.c:33
#17 0x0000555555555181 in main ()

The allocation comes from glibc allocating buffer for stdout in https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/fileops.c#L752 .


What I don't get is why, on my x86_64 Linux computer, the difference is specifically 25600 bytes.

Normally, stdio package initializes itself at the first call of any of the function in its interface.  This means allocating space for the buffered streams for at least, stdin, stdout and stderr (well, stderr is not buffered, by default, but probably the stdio package will allocate by default the best amount of buffer memory for the case you configure it to do full buffering)
This means that the file descriptors of the three descriptors be queried (via ioctl(2) calls)  to get from the system the optimal buffer size, and this justifies the amount you see.  For example, the ufs filesystem type in BSD derived systems propose a default buffer of 16kb to best buffer the file i/o.  This would justify upto three calls to malloc for 48kb (plus malloc overhead, plus malloc margin to avoid calling the system again the next time you call malloc) in the first call to printf().
Also, you must think that, if malloc(3) is called to do the allocation, then at the first attempt, malloc will not only get a chunk of memory from the system to allocate only those three buffers, but probably more to allow it to work seamesly for a while before having to request more memory to the kernel.
